# IPSec VPN using NEVPNManager does not disconnect on sleep

Tags: ios, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I'm working on an IPSec VPN solution for macOS. I've managed to get a VPN configuration installed via NEVPNManager and everything works. Except, my requirment is to disconnect the VPN when mac goes to sleep. Below is the IPSec profile which I am using.

```
- (void)setupIPSec

{

    [self configVPNKeychain];

    NSData *passwordData = [self persistentReferenceForSavedPassword:@"username" service:kPasswordReference account:@"account" description:@"login"];

    NSData *sharedSecretData = [self persistentReferenceForSavedPassword:@"54343333" service:kSharedSecretReference account:@"account" description:@"IPSec Shared Secret"];



    // config IPSec protocol

    NEVPNProtocolIPSec *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
    p.username = @"username012134";
    p.serverAddress = @"ipsec.route.com";

    // get password persistent reference from keychain
    p.passwordReference = passwordData;
    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
    p.sharedSecretReference = sharedSecretData;
    p.useExtendedAuthentication = YES;
    p.disconnectOnSleep = YES;   // This is were I am setting YES to disconnect the VPN connection when on Sleep.

    [NEVPNManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;
    [NEVPNManager sharedManager].protocolConfiguration = p;
    [NEVPNManager sharedManager].localizedDescription = @"VPN";

}
```

Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: I don't see documentation explicitly stating it, but my expectation is that you should set the configuration before setting `enabled` to YES.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Let me give it a try and will update you accordingly.

Comment: No luck its still the same :(